# Updating paperclip filename after renaming model?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

How do I update the filenames of all paperclip objects after I rename a model and update the table name?

Paperclip stores them in a path that contains the model name. I am looking for an automatic way probably in a migration that would update the file paths.

Comment: do you need to update the records? because you have the option to override the classname that paperclip uses to save and you don't have to change your data

Comment: I need to rename them and use the name for another model.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pass to the method, the option for the new `url`:

This are the defaults that PaperClip uses:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/95acf3b898bd782f4429d42fd2d8812505390328/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L24

```
{
  path: ':rails_root/public:url',
  url: '/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
}
```

You'll have to override the behaviour and change `:class` to your new model name, the path is determined dynamically trough the url:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, url: '/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename' 
end
```

You'll have to be careful in using the old model name in other model, unless you override also the other model `url` option.

Comment: `attachment_file_name` only contains the filename not the actual path.